# show open/closed based on array of opening hours + timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array containing opening hours. I also have an object with the timezone for the opening hours. The array looks like this:

```
const timezone = 'Europe/Brussels';

const array = [{
  day: 'mon',
  startTime: '12.00pm',
  endTime: '04.00pm'
},
{
  day: 'mon',
  startTime: '05.00pm',
  endTime: '08.00pm'
},
{
  day: 'tue',
  startTime: '08.00am',
  endTime: '12.00pm'
},
{
  day: 'tue',
  startTime: '01.00pm',
  endTime: '05.00pm'
},
...]
```

I now want to show an "is open" image on my website (react frontend, nodejs backend), but I really have no clue how to do this.

If it's a monday, 02.00pm and I'm in Brussels, the place must be "open". But if it's 02.00pm in New York, it's 08.00pm in Brussels and the image should say "closed".

I'm familiar with moment/moment-timezone library. Can someone point me to the right direction to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the [`date.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to always get the date in the correct timezone and format: `const d = new Date();
d.toLocaleString('be-FR', { timeZone: 'Europe/Brussels' })`

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at it!